# JS return object by array index

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to convert an array to an object (keyed by the first element).

```
foo = [1,2]

function convert_foo(foo) {
    return { foo[0]: foo[1] };
}
```

The following is not valid Javascript: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`.

I've also tried:

```
function convert_foo(foo) {
    return ({ foo[0]: foo[1] });
}
```

EDIT:

It's possible this way, but I was wondering if there was a way to return it in one line.

```
function convert_foo(foo) {
    var obj = {}
    obj[foo[0]] = foo[1];
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dynamic keys (aka *computed property names* in ECMAScript 2015), you have to put the key in square brackets:

```js
function convert_foo(foo) {
    return { [foo[0]]: foo[1] };
}

console.log(convert_foo([1, 2]));
```

Comment: Thanks I'll accept it. Is there a way to use this with `map`? i.e. `foo_array.map(foo => { [foo[0]]: foo[1] })`?

Comment: With `map()`, you mean mapping an array to an object with multiple properties?

Comment: I just found it. `foo_array.map(foo => ({ [foo[0]]: foo[1] }))`. Wrapping the return `()`.

Answer (score 1):

With the upcoming [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), that is [already supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility) on some browsers, you can also do something like this:

```js
function convert_foo(foo)
{
    return Object.fromEntries([foo]);
}

console.log(convert_foo([1, 2]));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```